# SQL Server query: Como obtener un solo registro, de un inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes tablas , quisiera obtener el resultado 
que menciono en el ejemplo. Espero puedan orientarme un poco. Gracias.

```
Tabla: TR

| idt | vt |
-------------
| 1  | 1101 |
| 2  | 1102 |
| 3  | 1103 |
-------------


Tabla TE

| ide | ve  | idt
------------------
| 1  | E101 | 1 | 
| 2  | E102 | 1 |  
| 3  | E103 | 2 |
| 4  | E104 | 3 |

------------------


Al hacer el INNER entre TR y TE

| idt | vt  | ve
------------------
| 1  | 1101 | E101  | 
| 1  | 1101 | E102  | 
| 2  | 1102 | E103  | 
| 3  | 1103 | E104  | 
----------------------


Lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente:

| idt | vt  | ve      ve2
---------------------------
| 1  | 1101 | E101  | E102  
| 2  | 1102 | E103  | 
| 3  | 1103 | E104  | 
----------------------
```

Comment: ¿hasta cuántos distintos ve puede haber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el número de columnas que tiene el resultado es previsible, puedes valerte de la clausula [`pivot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) de SQL Server para lograr tu cometido. Esta operación *transforma* filas en columnas, valiéndose de una función de agregación.

Para lograr el resultado exacto, yo primero calculo el *número de columna*, con la concatenación entre `'ve'` y el número de fila que corresponde a cada registro dividiéndolo en grupos por `idt`.

Finalmente, hago el `pivot` utilizando el valor de esta columna. En este caso, estoy incluyendo solamente 2 columnas `[ve1]` y `[ve2]`. Esto se puede ampliar fácilmente, siempre que, como ya dije, el número de columnas se previsible.

Para la agregación, ya que realmente no hay nada que agregar, y que la columna resultante es de tipo `char` o similar, me valgo de `min()`.

La consulta quedaría algo como:

```
with tr as (
select 1 idt, '1101' vt
union all select 2, '1102'
union all select 3, '1103'
)
,
te as (
select 1 ide, 'E101' VE, 1 idt
union all select 2, 'E102', 1
union all select 3, 'E103', 2
union all select 4, 'E104', 3 
)
,
base as (
select   te.idt
       , tr.vt
       , te.ve
       , 've' + cast(row_number() over (partition by te.idt order by te.ve) as varchar) num_columna
  from te
       inner join tr on tr.idt = te.idt
)
select idt, vt, [ve1], [ve2]
  from base
       pivot (min(ve)
         for num_columna in ([ve1], [ve2]) ) as PivotTable
```

Que produce el siguiente resultado:

```
idt         vt   ve1  ve2
----------- ---- ---- ----
1           1101 E101 E102
2           1102 E103 NULL
3           1103 E104 NULL

(3 rows affected)
```